# How to performlick on listview?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I already asked the question but without success.

So I have a list of bluetooth devices. I'm assuming I have only one item (one device) in this list. When I click to this item, onListItemClick() method from ListActivity is called. What I would like to do is selecting this item without the click of the user so I 'd like to simulate a click with the function performclick().

Here is my code :

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity {
private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;
private Handler mHandler;
BluetoothCrashResolver bluetoothCrashResolver;
//UUID[] uuids = { UUID.fromString("1811")};


private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
// Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.title_devices);
    mHandler = new Handler();


    if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }


    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();


    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    if (!mScanning) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(null);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_stop).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_scan).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setActionView(
                R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_scan:
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
            scanLeDevice(true);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_stop:
            scanLeDevice(false);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bluetoothCrashResolver = new BluetoothCrashResolver(this.getApplicationContext());
    bluetoothCrashResolver.start();

    // Ensures Bluetooth is enabled on the device.  If Bluetooth is not currently enabled,
    // fire an intent to display a dialog asking the user to grant permission to enable it.
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    // Initializes list view adapter.
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    scanLeDevice(true);

    if(mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() >0) {
        getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, 0);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
    bluetoothCrashResolver.stop();
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    final BluetoothDevice device = mLeDeviceListAdapter.getDevice(position);
    if (device == null) return;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    intent.putExtra(DeviceControlActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS, device.getAddress());
    if (mScanning) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        mScanning = false;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}



private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);

        mScanning = true;
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

// Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mInflator = DeviceScanActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if(!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
       if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else{
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        }
        return view;
    }
}

// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                bluetoothCrashResolver.notifyScannedDevice(device, mLeScanCallback);
            }
        });
    }
};

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
}
```

}

in onResume() function, I have added those lines :

```
if(mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() >0) {
    getListView().performItemClick(getListView().getAdapter().getView(0, null, null), 0, 0);
}
```

but nothing changed. I still have to click myself to the item and I can't see where the problem comes from. And if I put off the line
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() >0

the app crashes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing `null` for both `convertView` and `parent` you're essentially creating a new parentless view. Clicking it won't call the `ListView`'s `onClickListener`.

You should get the view directly from the `ListView`, not the adapter:

```
list.performItemClick(list.getChildAt(0), 0, list.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
```

**Update:**

Try delaying the click:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        list.performItemClick(list.getChildAt(0), 0, list.getItemIdAtPosition(0));
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Yes but the only way I can access to the listview is with getListView() because I don't have something like "Listview list;" in onResume().

Comment: @Bob `getListView()` should be fine if no error is thrown. However I guess the ListView could be not yet be ready when calling the click, so try delaying it as in my updated answer.

Comment: Yesss, that worked !!! finally !! Thank you so much ! ;) . It's been two days, I was looking for it. Thanks again. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to make your answer useful :(

Comment: @Bob good that you found the problem. But you should try something like `getListView().post()` or another way of deciding when the ListView is ready. Because setting a fixed delay is not the best way to fix this.

Comment: Okay, I'll search about it. Thanks for your help and advices.